# How to extract 'div' value by using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to get 8.9 from follow html tag by using BeautifulSoup.

```
<div rating-value="8.9" ratings-count="23" product-url="lenovo-v14-ada-amd-ryzen-3-3250u-8-gb-vram-256-gb-ssd-14-inch-windows-home-1-82c6006cuk/version.asp" class="ng-isolate-scope">



import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

website = 'https://www.laptopsdirect.co.uk/ct/laptops-and-netbooks/laptops?fts=laptops'
response = requests.get(website)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'lxml')

results = soup.find_all('div', class_='OfferBox')

name = results[0].find('a', class_='offerboxtitle').get_text()
price = results[0].find('span', class_='offerprice').get_text()
review_rating = results[0].find('')
print(review_rating)
```

I tried:

> review_rating = results[0].find('div.rating-value')
>
> None

> review_rating = results[0].find('div')['rating-value']
>
> KeyError: 'rating-value'

I'm not familiar with BeautifulSoup yet, so I failed.

Please teach me how to get 8.9?

Thanks

Comment: this should work `results[0].find('div')['rating-value']` but without knowing `results[0]` so can you share URL for better understading!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for the data in wrong tag. *The HTML shows the data inside a `<div>` but in the soup, it is present inside `<star-rating>`.*

The rating is present as an attribute of a tag called `<star-rating>`. Just extract the data from it.

```
price = results[0].find('span', class_='offerprice').get_text()
review_rating = results[0].find('star-rating').get('rating-value')
print(review_rating)
```

```
8.9
```

Answer (score 1):

You might use `.get` method for retrieving attributes values as follows

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = '''<div rating-value="8.9" ratings-count="23" product-url="lenovo-v14-ada-amd-ryzen-3-3250u-8-gb-vram-256-gb-ssd-14-inch-windows-home-1-82c6006cuk/version.asp" class="ng-isolate-scope">'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
print(soup.find("div").get("rating-value"))
```

output

```
8.9
```

Keep in mind that what `.get` return is `str` (`"8.9"`).

Comment: I tried > review_rating = results[0].find('div').get('rating-value')
print(review_rating) #result : None

Comment: @Peters7 what is output of doing `print(results[0].find("div"))`? Is this `div` you want to process or something other?

Comment: @DaweoThis is for testing single page only and 'div' is must get value for review rating. Because I can't get star images for review rating.